# How to display and hide rows of a table by clicking table header?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use getElementById() method to view rows.I want to click on "Header" and to show the following rows. How to use getElementById() correctly? You can run the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKUO03TZ4IZC).

[image]

```js
function hide() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
  for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells\[i\]; i++) {
    cell.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="hide()"> Header </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Quit </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the current result? Please make fiddle

Comment: The code you linked does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, what you are doing wrong, is firstly, i can't find document.getElementById(**"mytab1"**); mytab1 id, I mean for mytab1 to show, you have to create a corresponding id. Now to recreate an example of yours, try this,

```
   <table id="mytab1">
    <tr>
    <th onclick="hide()" style="cursor:pointer;"> Header </th>
    </tr>


    <tr ><td> 1 </td></tr>

    <tr ><td><a style="cursor:pointer;"> Quit </a></td></tr>

    </table>


    <script>
 function hide() {
                var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
                alltr = table.querySelectorAll("tr");

                for (var i = 1; i < alltr.length-1; i++) {
                    alltr[i].style.display = (alltr[i].style.display == "none") ? "" : "none";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

try that and see if it works, if it doesn't tell me, lets solve it together.

Comment: Hello is not working chek it here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKUOCSESGB0V

Comment: @Dimitris I am looking at your code will, edit mine a sec.

Comment: Just use 'alltr.length' instead of 'alltr.length-1'  to show hide all rows.
Also all rows should be hidden before click.

Answer (score 1):

I've use slightly different method as compared to the existing answers. Also, this uses plain Javascript, instead of jQuery.

First of all, instead of hiding the elements through inline styles, you can use CSS:

```
table.bodyHidden tr:nth-child(odd),
table.bodyHidden tr:nth-child(even) {
  display: none;
}

table.bodyHidden tr:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Then, if you have multiple tables, and do not wish to hardcode the ID of the table in the script, you can navigate to the `<table>` element in the click handler through `event.target` and then toggle the `bodyHidden` class on it.

```js
function hide(event) {
  var tableNode = undefined;
  var currentNode = event.target;
  
  // Search for the table node among the parent elements of the element that triggered the click event.
  while(tableNode == undefined) {
    if(currentNode.nodeName == 'TABLE') {
      tableNode = currentNode;    
    } else {
      currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }
  }
  
  // Toggle the bodyHidden class.
  if(tableNode.classList.contains("bodyHidden")) {
    tableNode.classList.remove("bodyHidden");
  } else {
    tableNode.classList.add("bodyHidden");
  }
}
```

```css
table.bodyHidden tr:nth-child(odd),
table.bodyHidden tr:nth-child(even) {
  display: none;
}

table.bodyHidden tr:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="hide(event)"> Header </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Quit </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can get this output.

```js
$(function() {
  var $rows = $('#mytab1 tbody');
  $("#mytab1 th").on("click", function() {
    // alert("Clicked");
    $rows.hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytab1">
  <thead>
    <th> Header </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Quit </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```